# Should I be animating SVG elements by updating attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg

I've just started out with SVG and have gathered enough information to see that animating these objects is not the same as animating canvas objects. With canvas objects, the canvas is redrawn on every frame, but it seems like with SVG you aren't supposed to be thinking in terms of frames and FPS, but rather in terms of seconds and delays by using the built in `<animate>` tag.

While I appreciate all the out of the box functionality for SVG animations, I've built up quite an understanding *(and library)* for how to get my animations working together on canvas **using the frames and a timeline paradigm.**

I know there is timeline and scheduling support for SVG with libraries like `GSAP` or `SVG.js` but I much prefer thinking in terms of `FPS` and and `frameCount`.

I was wondering if I might be able to continue using this paradigm, but instead **simply update the attributes of my SVG objects on each frame iteration** and let the DOM re-render the positions instead of figuring out a way to describe the animation in the `<animate>` tag.

I'm completely open to suggestions if using the `<animate>` tag isn't as finicky as I think it is for scheduling my animations/getting them to move together and any suggestions would be much appreciated.

My animation needs aren't to the likes of high performance websites, I just want to step through them to show people some math concepts as they progress.

Comment: You have free choice. Use [SMIL animation](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) (thats what you discovered), CSS [keyframes animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) or imperative Javascript animations, using the [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) interface. As long as performance is no concern, all are a fair bet. If that becomes a concern, [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/#toc-imperative-declarative) might be worth to consider

Comment: @ccprog Thank you so much. Let's say I was able to create an abstraction of a "Timeline" similar to the one I mentioned above, and this timeline was able to take in commands from the `frames` and `FPS` paradigm and generate the appropriate animation tags for the `SVG` elements, would that then be the best of both worlds? _(imperative vs. declarative)_.

Comment: This is pretty broad and certainly unspecific. Maybe if you post some code to show which kind of description you currently use it would be possible to give some hints on where to go next.

Comment: @ccprog Creating animation tags is declarative, meaning it can be optimized by the browser correct? This is good because it can cause things to run more smoothly. Declarative animation is described [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/#toc-imperative-declarative) as being faster and does not block the main thread. Javascript on the other hand is Imperative and does block the main thread. I'm wondering if I wrote javascript to generate these animation tags if that would be optimal. Thanks again! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The counter argument is that with a declarative language you are always battling its vocabulary. What if it does not know how to interpolate between certain values? What if a certain easing function is not supported? Two concepts I see developers struggling with regularly are morphing of paths and interpolations over multiple parameters (two-dimensional geometry, mostly). That is why I asked about code examples. If we can see what kind of things you are animating, we might be able to guess at the difficult edge cases.

Comment: @ccprog Completely understand, I currently have support in my library for multiple parameter interpolation by updating the SVG's attributes "manually" with javascript and don't want to have difficulty redesigning this feature. I appreciate your offer to point out some of the difficult edge cases in generating `<animate>` tags with javascript, but I feel for my use case the optimization isn't needed. Perhaps someone will create a version of this one day, but I don't think that's going to be me :). Thanks for all the help in clearing up my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Updating SVG element attributes is a completely fine way to go about animating them. It can be more performant than clearing all elements in your main SVG tag, and redrawing - but that depends on the drawing, browser, and animation details. But, SVG renders surprisingly quickly, so if you are just stepping through tailored frames to demonstrate a concept, and if it would be more convenient to think of each frame independently, you should be completely fine to also clear and redraw. If your project is intended for a website, make sure to test your implementation on Chrome and Firefox at least as they have slight differences.